# Django/Apache Server Down but 403

Tags: django

i have a Django Site running on Debian server. The thing is that it crushed out and is giving now a 403 Forbidden error. The site run for 2 years without an issue. I shutdown the apache2 server and while was not running I could still see the 403 error. Normal trick was to see 500 while was down.
Can someone pls advise? Why is this caching?

I've followed all the steps from other past 403 questions.

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/static/public/images/favicon.ico

Alias /media_files/ /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/media/
Alias /static/ /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/static/

<Location /robots.txt>
    SetHandler None
    Require all granted
</Location>

<Directory /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess pdpr.ro python-home=/home/pdpr_live/.virtualenvs/pdpr_env python-path=/home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr
WSGIProcessGroup pdpr.ro
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/hek_pd/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/pdpr_live/live/pdpr/hek_pd>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

This is how it looks the error log

```
[Wed Oct 09 06:25:01.851427 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 27870:tid 139906069127232] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2r mod_wsgi/4.5.11 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 09 06:25:01.851495 2019] [core:notice] [pid 27870:tid 139906069127232] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 10 20:33:26.321765 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 532:tid 140696571981888] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2r mod_wsgi/4.5.11 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 10 20:33:26.646183 2019] [core:notice] [pid 532:tid 140696571981888] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 10 21:11:53.656431 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 532:tid 140696571981888] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 10 21:11:53.734849 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 730:tid 139743432036416] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2r mod_wsgi/4.5.11 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 10 21:11:53.734959 2019] [core:notice] [pid 730:tid 139743432036416] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the new update brings a new setting to be made. On /etc/bind our structure had a DNS local server that had be correctly set. The way how the config was, was pointing to the incorrect 153 ip, despite the correct one was 183==>hence forbidden access on the 153. The new lines was changed to point correct to the IP that had the Django project and worked like a charm!